# Office 365 - Deleting Users With Status "Syncing" From Migration Job?

Tags: exchange, email-server, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration

Hoping someone can help answer this question for us - we currently have a hybrid setup for our Office 365 and are starting to migrate users' mailboxes from on prem Exch 2010 to O365. We have a rather large migration job that is running and it's only synced a small number of users' mailboxes thus far (30), so the rest are either syncing or a few failed.

To at least get some mailboxes migrated today (the 30 that are synced), is there a "proper" way to remove the other mailboxes that are still syncing or failed from the migration job so that the 30 that are synced can complete? To be more specific, for the remote move selected in the admin portal, the job will not complete automatically (until I select to complete the migration job). I've deleted failed mailboxes from a migration job before (while other mailboxes were "synced"), but have never deleted mailboxes still "syncing" and so not sure if this will cause any issues? Appreciate any help and advice in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Suspend-MoveRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364735(v=exchg.141).aspx) to suspend move request, then use [Remove-MoveRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351276(v=exchg.141).aspx) to remove it.
If you want to suspend whole migration batch, run [Stop-MigrationBatch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219168(v=exchg.160).aspx).